# iphone - get tiles of the visible part of the map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I need to be able to get the tiles that are contained in the map I'm showing.

My partner is using Android and he is using this algorithm to translate Coordinates to Tiles, apparently Google Maps has divided the world in tiles, and I need the tiles that are contained in the maps in order to request info to my server that is related to those tiles.

Do you know how it can be done for iOs?

Here's the way to do it in android(maybe it will help):

```
lat = mapView.getBounds()[1][0]/1E6;
lon = mapView.getBounds()[0][1]/1E6;
int xtile1 = (int)Math.floor( (lon + 180) / 360 * (1<<zoom) ) ;
int ytile1 = (int)Math.floor( (1 - Math.log(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(lat)) + 1 / Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat))) / Math.PI) / 2 * (1<<zoom) ) ;
lon = mapView.getBounds()[1][1]/1E6;
int xtile2 = (int)Math.floor( (lon + 180) / 360 * (1<<zoom) ) ;             
lat = mapView.getBounds()[0][0]/1E6;
int ytile2 = (int)Math.floor( (1 - Math.log(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(lat)) + 1 / Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat))) / Math.PI) / 2 * (1<<zoom) ) ;
```

First problem, zoom in Android and iOs is not the same, so I will getting different data even though Im showing the same piece of map.

I need a way to work it around that. Or another way of getting the tiles in iOS

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see a use case. Do you really bind your data to Google's tiles? Or do you use geographic coordinates? If the latter, then getting the visible bounds of the map is the way to go.

Comment: I use the tiles, since we have a program running in our server that uses the API of Google maps and I need the tiles to get the info from our server.

Comment: It sounds like this is likely to break the Terms. Please give a URL to demonstrate that it doesn't.

Comment: I can't give a URL right now.
How can it break the Terms?, Im trying to find out the tiles contained in the vieweable part of the map and then get info on those tiles.

Comment: i'm in the same boat. this isn't breaking any terms, its just trying to use a WMS server to get tiles and place them on the MKMapKit (for my case). google tiles is a standard, it just breaks the world up into X,Y tiles for a given zoom level. at zoom level 1, you have 1 tile, zoome level 2, you have 4, etc etc.  need to find out which tile is in the map view for a given zoom level so you can make a wms request for that tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example you will see how it is done.
A very well done approach 
https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo